# GHC existentially quantified singleton

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm using GHC 7.10 and the `singletons` package. There's a GADT named [SomeSing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.0.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:SomeSing) in this library that allows you to existentially quantify a singleton. It's definition looks like this:

```
data SomeSing (kproxy :: KProxy k) where
  SomeSing :: Sing (a :: k) -> SomeSing ('KProxy :: KProxy k)
```

And it works great. We can wrap up a singleton with this so that only the kind is known, not the type.

I wanted to create a variant, a similar wrapper that would allow me to wrap up a singleton and the result of a type function applied to it:

```
data SomeSingWith (kproxy :: KProxy k) (f :: TyFun k n -> *) where
  SomeSingWith :: Sing (a :: k) -> Apply g a -> SomeSingWith ('KProxy :: KProxy k) g
```

However, I get this error:

```
Data constructor ‘SomeSingWith’ cannot be GADT-like in its *kind* arguments
  SomeSingWith :: forall (k :: BOX) (g :: TyFun k * -> *) (a :: k).
                  Sing a -> Apply g a -> SomeSingWith 'KProxy g
In the definition of data constructor ‘SomeSingWith’
In the data declaration for ‘SomeSingWith’
```

What does this mean? And can it be fixed, or is what I'm doing impossible in GHC?

Comment: A GADT is an algebraic datatype indexed by types, but for whatever technical reason, you cannot have a kind-indexed GADT. This is what the error means.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The second argument of `TyFun` needs to be kinded `*` instead of being allowed to be any arbitrary kind. This makes sense. However, the error message associated with the mistake is not helpful.

```
data SomeSingWith (kproxy :: KProxy k) (f :: TyFun k * -> *) where
  SomeSingWith :: Sing (a :: k) -> Apply g a -> SomeSingWith ('KProxy :: KProxy k) g
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `kproxy` as index for `SomeSingWith`, because `k`  is apparent from `f`'s kind.

Comment: The definition here is identical to the one in the question. Was that intentional?

Comment: @ReidBarton Sorry. I discovered the solution half-way through writing the question, but I decided to finish it out anyway. It looks like I did end up posting the solution in the question by accident. I'll change it to the non-working version (which is a one-character difference).